# Convert ddmmyyy character to DATE

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How do I convert a character in the form of ddmmyyyy to a DATE type?

Is there method to format the character variable? For Example take first two characters of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
define variable s as character no-undo initial "10092018".
define variable d as date no-undo.

d = date( integer( substring( s, 3, 2 )), integer( substring( s, 1, 2 )), integer( substring( s, 5, 4 ))).

display d format "99/99/9999".
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I just couldn't find the correct function to use. Just for future reference here's the documentation on SUBSTRING function: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/substring-function.html

Answer (score 2):

The `DATE` function can be used for that:

> `DATE ( month, day, year )`

or

> `DATE ( string )`

If you have set your date format setting to `dmy`, both of the following will work:

```
define variable cDate  as character no-undo.
define variable dDate1 as date      no-undo.
define variable dDate2 as date      no-undo.

cDate  = "31122018".
dDate1 = date(cDate).
dDate2 = date (int(substring(cDate,3,2)) /*month*/,
               int(substring(cDate,1,2)) /*day*/,
               int(substring(cDate,5))   /*year*/).
display dDate1 dDate2.
```